# Restarting all tabs in SuperPuTTY at once?

Tags: windows-7, superputty

I have opened a couple of sessions on [SuperPuTTY](https://code.google.com/p/superputty/). The Internet got interrupted for a few minutes, which cause my SSH sessions to be disconnected in SuperPuTTY. Is there any way to restart all tabs in SuperPuTTY at once?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SuperPuTTY supports a feature called layouts, this allows you to open your sessions and layout your screen how you prefer. You can then click File -> Save Layout (CTRL+S), if you have your layouts window open (View -> Layouts) you can double click your saved layout and it will open all sessions you had previously opened in your layout.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's indeed a pis-aller, but ideally I'd like to avoid creating a new layout it's time I need to restart a bunch of sessions at once.